# How to prevent NHibernate from calling Flush during a session that only reads data

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When I run this code, the List method causes a flush of the Developer. I don't want this to happen.

```
Developer developer = null;
IEnumerable<Language> languages = null;
using (var session = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var trx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    developer = session.Get<Developer>(id);
    languages = session.CreateCriteria<Language>().List<Language>();
}
```

If I swap the lines inside the `using` so that the languages are retrieved first, then the developer is not flushed. But I don't want to have to remember to do that unless there's a good reason.

Do I need to change my mapping? Here's what it looks like now:

```
class DeveloperMap : ClassMap<Developer>
{
    public DeveloperMap()
    {
        Table("Developers");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        References(x => x.FavoriteLanguage).Cascade.None();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.AssignedProjects)
            .Cascade.None()
            .Table("DevelopersProjects")
            .FetchType.Join();
    }
}
```

Here's the Developer class too, just in case that helps.

```
public class Developer
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Language FavoriteLanguage { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Project> AssignedProjects { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't changing data, there shouldn't be a flush at all, unless you have a ghost (incorrect mapping that is forcing an unnecessary update). I suggest that you verify (with a profiler, checking the SQL log, etc) what is being flushed exactly.

To prevent automatic flushes, just set `session.FlushMode` to anything other than `Auto` (the default) or `Always`. `Commit` is, in my opinion, the most practical behavior.

Comment: Even though the FlushEntity event is being raised, with @event.Entity referencing the Developer object, the flush seems to be executing no DB commands. SQL Profiler only shows the expected SELECTs, and no UPDATEs. Does that mean my mapping is correct? ... I see [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) that Flush is called "from some invocations of Find() or Enumerable()." Apparently this is one of those invocations. ... Setting FlushMode to Commit prevents FlushEntity from firing, which answers my question, but I do wonder if I have an incorrect mapping.

Comment: You're good to go, with any FlushMode. That was just NH doing its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've noted on several occasions that wrapping read-only operations inside a `Transaction` tends to cause undesired effects. As Diego mentions, the `Flush` might be caused by an incorrect mapping.

I understand there might be some performance issues with this, as noted [here](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/donotuseimplicittransactions). However, if you are only reading you shouldn't need a `using(Transaction)` block.

Try removing it, as such,

```
using (var session = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    developer = session.Get<Developer>(id);
    languages = session.CreateCriteria<Language>().List<Language>();
}
```

Comment: This does prevent the flush from happening. I suppose this could work for me, as long as I don't need to use the 2nd level cache.

Comment: @Andrew True. It all depends on how much information you need, and how complex is the operation.